# is it possible to use GTK SourceView in GTK# / mono?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

is it possible to use GTK `SourceView` control in c# application written using mono / GTK#?

I did only find 2 empty repositories under github and links that are linked from mono official pages are defunct. Is there some alternative wrapper?